# Формат строки java

Tags: java

У меня есть строка

```
String a = "f1950/10/22";
```

как мне сделать с неё

```
String b = "1950-10-22";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо:

1. Сформировать шаблон для имеющейся даты:

   `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("'f'yyyy/MM/dd");`
2. Распарсить вашу строку по шаблону в дату:

   `Date date = sdf.parse("f1950/10/22");`
3. Сформировать шаблон для требуемой даты:

   `SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");`
4. Преобразовать дату из п2 с помощью шаблона из п3:

   `String result = sdf.format(date);`

Comment: спасибо огромное!!!